# Am I entitled to get my car deposit back?

Tags: car, deposits

I recently put down a $1000 deposit on a vehicle that is at a dealership out of state. The vehicle that I put the deposit down on is “in transit” and is not technically on the lot.

It’s been two months since I put down the deposit and the vehicle is still “in transit” so I am wanting to go with another vehicle that is available now.

The deposit was done over the phone via credit card and no contract etc was signed. I realize now that this probably wasn’t the smartest thing to do but I also wasn’t expecting the vehicle to take months to arrive. The receipt does not state whether the deposit was refundable or non-refundable.

Am I entitled to get my deposit back?

Comment: Have you talked to the dealer yet? What did they say?

Comment: I had a similar situation. The dealer kept saying it’s coming, but I began to fear he was just stringing me along. I even shopped for other cars but I didn’t find anything on a lot that matched what I wanted. Finally after about 4 months or so, I got my car. I had that car for 21 years...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it was not a scam, the dealer should be willing to give you the money back.
Worst case, if he declines, call your credit card company and tell them that the seller didn’t deliver as agreed, and cancel the charge.

Comment: "Assuming it is not a scam" is the key. Best case this is a shady dealership that took the money without any written agreement on what it was for or if it was refundable. Worst case... this is a $1,000 lesson on "get it in writing".

Comment: The dealer should be willing to give the money back, but I'm betting they aren't legally obligated to do so unless you sue them over it. The credit card dispute is probably your best option.